# Load remote url in react-bootstrap modal component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

How to load remote url in [react-bootstrap](http://react-bootstrap.github.io) modal component?

Below is my code.

```
var React = require("react");
var Router = require("react-router");
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap');
var Modal = ReactBootstrap.Modal;
module.exports = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
  return {
    htmlShow: false,
    htmlUrl: null,
    htmlTitle: 'this is title'
  };    
},
hideModal: function(){
    this.setState({
      htmlShow: false
    });
},
componentDidMount: function(){
    //here I want to set the url and make the modal load the url content in the modal-body
    this.setState({
        htmlShow: true,
        htmlUrl: 'www.google.com'
    });
},
render: function() {
    return (
        <Modal ref={(c) => this.modal = c} onHide={this.hideModal} show={this.state.htmlShow} >
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title id="preview-modal-title-lg">{this.state.htmlTitle}</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
             <Modal.Body>
                "loading..."
             </Modal.Body>
             <Modal.Footer>
               <Button onClick={this.hideModal}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )
} })
```

I want to set the url dynamically. I wonder whether React-Bootstrap Modal can load the remote url. In plain bootstrap modal, this is possible. Is there any nice way to do this in react-bootstrap modal component?

Comment: Hi @m-zhang,   What have you done so far? http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: problem description updated. :)